# matplotlib.image distorting colours

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

So i'm reading this image

[image: lena.bmp]

with im=matplotlib.image.imread("lena.bmp") but i get this

[image: lena but with wrong colours]

when i do this matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(im)

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455891/matplotlib-changes-jpg-image-color

Comment: You need `plt.imshow(..., cmap='gray', vmin=0, vmax=255)`. The default colormap is viridis.